# Parsing a namespace in Groovy when the namespace is not specified in the root element?

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I'm writing a Groovy script to parse a SOAP response from a web service, and the XML specifies a namespace in the middle of the document:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <AuthenticateResponse xmlns="KaseyaWS">
         <AuthenticateResult>
            <SessionID>xxxxxxxxxx</SessionID>
            <Method>Authenticate</Method>
            <TransactionID>4228</TransactionID>
            <ErrorMessage/>
            <ErrorLocation/>
         </AuthenticateResult>
      </AuthenticateResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The namespace doesn't specify a name, it just applies to everything within the `<AuthenticateResponse xmlns="KaseyaWS">` node, but I'd still like to be able to parse it.

The [GPathResult](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html) returned from the `parseText()` method allows you to call `declareNameSpace(Map m)` to add a namespace to the document like so:

```
def slurper = XmlSlurper().parseText(someXMLText).declareNamespace(soap:'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
```

But I don't rightly understand how to call `declareNamespace()` on the [GPathResult](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html) to specify the anonymous namespace (`xmlns="KaseyaWS"`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XmlSlurper` can be namespace unaware. So you can parse without worrying about the namespace as:

```
def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(someXMLText)
def result = slurper.Body.AuthenticateResponse.AuthenticateResult

assert result.SessionID == 'xxxxxxxxxx' 
assert result.Method == 'Authenticate' 
assert result.TransactionID == '4228'
```

You can use [`XmlParser`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlParser.html) if you need more control over the namespace and the way the xml is parsed to Node:

```
def soapNs = new groovy.xml.Namespace(
                    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", 'soap')
def ns = new groovy.xml.Namespace("KaseyaWS", "test") //Dummy NS Prefix
def parser = new XmlParser().parseText(someXMLText)

assert parser[soapNs.Body][ns.AuthenticateResponse]
                  .AuthenticateResult.SessionID.text() == 'xxxxxxxxxx'
assert parser[soapNs.Body][ns.AuthenticateResponse]
                  .AuthenticateResult.Method.text() == 'Authenticate'
```

Comment: Note: if you want that XmlParser be namespace unaware, like XmlSlurper, you can user this `xmlParser.setNamespaceAware(false)`. Note: in my version (groovy 2.3.7) there is a bug that ignores this false parameter if we use it in XmlParser constructor. So, we must call the setter explicitly